# How to put a struct in json format?

Tags: c, json, struct

I have to put this struct :

```
typedef struct                  
{
   int codigo_pedido;
   char descricao[20];

}PEDIDO;
```

in Json format. The Goal is, for anytime i acess it values i should do a thing like this, for Ex :
 Pedido.getString(codigo)(or anything like that to acess elements is JSON), to acess the value of codigo in the struct. I have been googling this but all the few solutions i saw were not very conclusive. I really appreciate some help, thank you.

Comment: It might be easier to save the struct in binary, because if you really want to use JSON, you will have to maintain a name for each of your struct members.

Comment: For a simple struct like this, you could also use `printf`: `PEDIDO pedido; printf("{\"codigo_pedido\":%d,\"descricao\":\"%s\"}", pedido.codigo_pedido, pedido.descricao);`

Comment: But is like a way of putting it in JSON it self ? my teacher said that i have to build this struct in JSON , i dont think that printf counts cause is just a print , im little bit confuse, Thank you

Comment: JSON is a normal file format, if you don't know what it is, you should look it up. You can use `fprintf` instead if you want to write to a file.